# kali linux pip install paramiko get ValueError

Tags: python, linux, pip

when I install paramiko with pip get error

ValueError: Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://127.0.0.1:1080/

This is the detailed error code I get:

```
root@kali-linux:~# pip install paramiko
Collecting paramiko
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
   r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py", line 154, in __init__
    "Unable to determine SOCKS version from %s" % proxy_url
ValueError: Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://127.0.0.1:1080/
```

And I don't what to do then I try to upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

get error prompt code

```
root@kali-linux:~# pip install --upgrade pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py", line 154, in __init__
    "Unable to determine SOCKS version from %s" % proxy_url
ValueError: Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://127.0.0.1:1080/
```

I use the command

```
set | grep -i all_proxy
```

get the prompt code

```
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:1080/
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:1080/
```

what should I do?

Comment: Are you using any proxy ?

Comment: @farbiondriven I do not use proxy

Comment: What 'set | grep -i all_proxy' command shows ?

Comment: ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:1080/ and 
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:1080/

Comment: exactly, so you have a proxy. you need to check with who setup it in your server. I have a temporary fix but needs to dig deeper to fix the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export all_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
export ALL_PROXY="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

if you don't want a proxy:

```
export all_proxy=""
export ALL_PROXY=""
```

Comment: you answer is correct.My problem is solved.Thanks very much ! Now my reputation less than 15 that can't vote you,but in the future I will compensate you !